# Automatic failover with PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, failover

PostgreSql 9.1 has master-slave synchronous replication. Suppose the master is machine A and the slave is machine B.

If the master fails, how does PostgreSQL know when to make the slave the master? What if the slave incorrectly thought the master was down because of a temporary network glitch on the master where the client program could still contact the master though.

And moreover, how would my client program know the slave in the new master and more importantly is ready to accept writes. Does the slave send a message to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Check [repmgr](http://www.repmgr.org/), it's one of its jobs is to deal with this issue.

Comment: though it explicitly doesn't take care of STONITH, so some external tools may still be required in some uses. It also doesn't do IP-based failover or proxy for clients, so you need plproxy or similar for that. It's helpful but not exactly a complete solution - yet.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend anyone use repmgr; it's been nothing but a time-sink for me at this point

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've found it to be buggy, poorly-designed and poorly-documented. I thought it would nicely abstract out some of the gnarly details of postgres replication and failover for some dev-ops scripts I'm doing, but instead I've spent much more time reverse engineering the gnarly details of repmgr, and still have to worry about the gnarly postgres details and I'm left with a system I don't fully understand instead of one I do.

Comment: @jberryman Have you talked to the repmgr developers about this? How was your experience with their support via the mailing-list?

Comment: @andreas-h they were pretty helpful on the forums. The two or three questions I had were responded to within 1-2 days IIRC.

Comment: @jberryman Same issue here.  What a waste.  I'd be very interested in what you ended up with instead.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to use a promotion-management system like repmgr or patroni.  Then you want to use some sort of a high availability proxy (could be pgbouncer or haproxy) to handle the actual abstraction so your applications do not need to know what system is master.

In answer to your question, most of these systems use a heartbeat to determine if there is a problem.  Patroni goes out over the etcd heartbeat.  Repmgr has its own heartbeat check.  With Repmgr you need to write hook scripts to take care of stonith, and so forth.